# Python set simulation time - One real minute = one hour in program

Tags: python, time

(sorry for my English)

I wrote a program which simulate water-cleaning process, and I display real time

`time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")` for example: 16:04:21

when one minute passed program show me: 16:05:21 but I would like to have this: 17:04:21

How change code to show ONE MINUTE IN REAL TIME TO ONE HOUR IN MY PROGRAM.

You know: One minute passed - my program thinking "One hour passed".

Comment: You can subtract two `datetime` objects and then multiply accordingly to scale.

Comment: Can you write a little example?

Answer (score 1):

```
_start = datetime.now()
def get_app_time():
   return _start + (datetime.now() - _start)*60
```

Then just call it when you need time